# C# Xamarin code to Linq statment

Tags: c#, android, linq, xamarin

Can anyone help me with getting these few lines of codes to a linq statement? Not very familiar with linq statement and would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me with it.

```
var searchFor = constraint.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < allUserList.Count; i++) {
    if (allUserList[i].FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchFor) ||
        allUserList[i].LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchFor)) {
        userInfoList.Add(allUserList[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use AddRange:

```
userInfoList.AddRange(allUserList.Where(a => 
                      a.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchfor) ||        
                      a.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchfor));
```

`Where` will return an `IEnumerable<UserObject>` which AddRange can use to populate the userInfoList

Comment: ToLower is a function so you need the braces

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend you to move out the `condition statement` into a separate method because it will make the code much more readable when you use Linq:

```
private bool UserNameContains(<your user name> user, string searchFor)
{
   return user.FirstName.IndexOf(searchFor, StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1 ||
          user.LastName.IndexOf(searchFor, StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
}
```

Notice that I am using `IndexOf(...) != -1`. This is because `Contains` uses the same method internally but with `StringComparision.Ordinal` argument. Assuming you do not care about casing it is much better to use `IndexOf(..., StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, this way you will avoid lowering the string characters and prevent from introducing a bug in case `searchFor` contains an upper character.

Then all you need to do is:

```
userInfoList.AddRange( allUserList.Where(user => this.UserNameContains(user, searchFor) );
```

or if `userInfoList` is new empty list, you can move the whole logic into its variable declaration:

```
var userInfoList = allUserList.Where(user => this.UserNameContains(user, searchFor).ToList();
```

Note that you should add `using System.Linq;` using directive in order to be able to use Linq extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory - no guarantees on exact syntax:

```
userInfoList = (from x in allUserList 
  where x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchFor) || 
  x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchFor) select x).ToList();
```

Comment: don't forget that he wants to add items to that list, not replace with the results of the query.